# Установка git на Linux Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, git

Хочу установить git, выполняю команду:

```
 real@real-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install git
```

> Чтение списков пакетов... Готово
>       Построение дерева зависимостей
>   Чтение информации о состоянии... Готово
>   Пакет git недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.    Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list
>   E: Для пакета git не найдены кандидаты на установку

Что за пакеты там еще надо?

Comment: а что там в sources.list?и что говорит     aptitude search git

Comment: Чем закончилось-то? Интересно же ...:)

Comment: Удалил Ubuntu...

Comment: ИМХО - зря так круто-то... А что в замен? Форточки?:)

Answer (score 1):

вот пакет:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/git-core

соответвенно устанавливать

```
sudo aptitude install git-core
```

Answer (score 0):

Пробовали добавить репозиторий?

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid main
```

Кроме того, есть [мнение](http://qutim.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=1887&start=100#p25422), что:

> В Ubuntu 10.04 слишком старая версия Qt: 4.6.3. Для сборки qutIM требуется минимум Qt-4.7. Как следствие Ubuntu 10.04 не поддерживается в виду того, что это старье.
>
> Хотите счастья и фантиков - обновитесь до более свежей версии системы.

Можно еще попробовать [ЭТО](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) Впрочем... то же самое:(

А [ТУТ](http://stimex-web.ru/blog/7/156#git) были?

ЗЫ В [установке из исходников](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git#Установка-из-исходников) не вижу ничего зазорного или сложного.

Comment: qutIM то тут причем.